# Planned Items & Tools does not remove Upload Changes queue when you uncheck the Use box

Tags: maximo, datasplice

When I click on the Use checkbox in the Planned Items and Tools screen, the blue upload changes column shows the icon that the record needs to be updated. When I uncheck the Use box, the Upload changes remains. So, even though I unchecked the box, the transaction still uploads to the server and the transaction is recorded instead of reset.

Whenever I checked on the row, Upload Changes would screen shows the queued record as "Use: true". What happens when I uncheck the the box? The Upload changes screen is as "Use: false". If I Upload Changes, the transaction goes through even though I unchecked the box and "Use: false"

I tried replacing "Use: false" with "Use: null" by creating a Verify Field, Modify Attribute event action where the condition was ${Use} == false . Then in Modify Attribute, for Use, I performed a test := Test (${Use} == false, null, null)

That made the Upload Changes show "Use: null" but the transaction still uploads and is processed as if I checked on the box.

[image: Use]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset the record instead.

- Event Handling, Under Event Bindings add Verify Field
- Event Actions, add Execute Command, Event Condition is `${Use} == false`
- Under Action Details, Command Type: RawCommand, Disposition: Client, ResetContext (check on), Command: resetRecord()

[image]

With this code in place, it has the desired effect of removing the transaction from the Upload Changes screen. Visually, you should see the upload changes icon disappear as well:

[image]